# Bing map v7 to v8 migration(DirectionManager class)

Tags: migration, bing-api, bing-maps

I am working on a project to migrate bing map from version7( v7) to v8 and following the procedure mentioned in the document

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx

Our bing map application (v7) is using methods beforeStepRender,beforeSummaryRender,afterWaypointRender  in DirectionManager Events class.As per the document (above link), these methods have been depricated in the v8. Could you please advise what would be the work around to achieve this in bing map v8?

Answer (score 0):

Use the directionsUpdated event. No need for all those other events.

Comment: Thanks! How to handle DirectionManager.setMapView() which is no longer present in v8?

Comment: DirectionManager automatically sets the view for you, so no need to manually set it.